# python load class name from another file always failed

Tags: python, import, namespaces

I got problem with below code:

in a.py file:

```
class CA():
def __init__(self):
    self.name= 'CA'

class F():
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'F'
    def calltest(self, obj_name):
        print "globals inside F.calltest:",globals()
        obj = globals().get(obj_name)
        if obj is None:
            raise ValueError("OBJ is not there!")
        obj.test()
```

in b.py file:

```
from a import *

class CB(CA):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'CB'
    def test(self):
        print 'I am class B!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "globals() in main:", globals()
    f_obj = F()
    f_obj.calltest('CB')
```

I got the results:

```
globals() in main: {'F': <class a.F at 0x023E8880>, '__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, 'CB': <class __main__.CB at 0x023E8810>, '__file__': 'C:\\Users\\\Downloads\\testcase\\b.py', '__package__': None, '__name__': '__main__', 'CA': <class a.CA at 0x02366AE8>, }

globals inside F.calltest: {'F': <class a.F at 0x023E8880>, '__builtins__': {'bytearray': <type 'bytearray'>, 'IndexError': <type 'exceptions.IndexError'>, 'all': <built-in function all>, 'help': Type help() for interactive help, or help(object) for help about object., 'vars': <built-in function vars>, 'SyntaxError': <type 'exceptions.SyntaxError'>, 'unicode': <type 'unicode'>, 'UnicodeDecodeError': <type 'exceptions.UnicodeDecodeError'>, 'memoryview': <type 'memoryview'>, 'isinstance': <built-in function isinstance>, 'copyright': Copyright (c) 2001-2012 Python Software Foundation.

File "C:\Users\Downloads\testcase\b.py", line 22, in <module>
    f_obj.calltest('CB')
File "C:\Users\lDownloads\testcase\a.py", line 21, in calltest
    raise ValueError("OBJ is not there!")
ValueError: OBJ is not there!
```

I know that in a.py file, class F object cannot know 'CB' class, but how can I solve the problem? I need to follow this format, but I tried editing globals(), no luck.

Comment: Each module has its own `globals`.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: "I need to follow this format" - why? It sounds like you've hit upon the wrong solution to some other problem and you're now asking how to make it work. If you ask about the problem you're trying to solve instead of your attempted solution, we can show you how to avoid this issue entirely.

Comment: Because current code is like this format, I cannot modify it, too costy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in a.py, it don't know CB, globals will not have CB. But F in a.py, so you have to tell him, like this:

```
class F():
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'F'
    def calltest(self, g, obj_name):
        obj = g.get(obj_name)
        if obj is None:
            raise ValueError("OBJ is not there!")
        obj.test()
```

Then in b.py main:

```
f_obj = F()
f_obj.calltest(globals(), 'CB')
```

This globals called in b.py, CB in globals

Comment: before obj.test(), we need to add _obj = obj() because now obj is a class type. getting the instance solve my problem. Thank you!